# Trying to figure out syntax to evaluate a string from the database using Django

Tags: python, django

I have question regarding a method eval, I initially wanted to create a separate
Def to handle user inputs answers from a form.. the problem is that method wont work because I don't know how to pass the local variable to another def since the random value will be different in the another function anyway.

Essentially the ran_puzz pulls a random puzzle from the database which has a value like "2+2" etc.

rand_puzz = Puzzles.objects.get(id = random_index).puzzle

So I figured since I did not know how to pass rand_puzz to another def, I decided to keep the variable and logic inside the def called "play" and return more then one value like" message and ran_puzz"

If you see the line "if eval(rand_puzz)== user_sub_ans;" // This is causes syntax errors

URLS:

```
url(r'^play/$', 'mathgame3.views.play'),
```

VIEWS:
    def play(request)

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    number_of_records = Puzzles.objects.count()
    random_index = int(random.random()*number_of_records)+1
    rand_puzz = Puzzles.objects.get(id = random_index).puzzle
    user_sub_ans = request.GET['answer']    
    if eval(rand_puzz)== user_sub_ans;
    message = 'correct'
    else:
    message = 'incorrect'
    return render(request, 'play.html', {'rand_puzz': rand_puzz, 'message': message})
else:
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```

Html: Just a chunk of some code from the form that the user inputs an answer to the puzzle.

```
    <form action="/play/" method = "get">
        <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:auto;">
<table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:auto; border:solid 1px">
<tr><td><label for="username">Question:</label></td>
<td>{{rand_puzz}}</td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="answer">Answer:</label></td>
<td><input type="number" name="answer" value="" id="answer"></td></tr>
<td> The answer is: {{message}}</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
</table>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: How did you manage to get one `if` statement right and the other so completely wrong?

Comment: These are segments of code. I am just not sure the syntax for eval

Comment: ... It's just a function.

Comment: Just as is the rand function, It took me days to figure out that I had to import into DJANGO the rand function for it to work, I am curious as to why eval gives syntax error.

Comment: `random` is a module. `if` is a statement.

Comment: Ok, so what is wrong with syntax? why does the the line if "eval(rand_puzz)== user_sub_ans" complain?

Comment: Why not compare it to the first one and find out?

Comment: I'll test something and get back to you.

Comment: I don't think syntax is an issue now. The problem is that It cannot get the value and compare it with the eval. I really can't figure this framework out after spending hours trying to play around with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That should probably be something like:

```
if eval(rand_puzz)== user_sub_ans:
     message = 'correct'
else:
     message = 'incorrect'
```

The `puzzle` field does not get its value from any user input I hope.

Comment: No, The puzzles are strings of operations that are inserted in the database already, they are randomly pulled from the database by a randomly generated Id which is used to output to the html page, 

for Example
question : 2+2 
answer: [form input from the user: '2']

then using the get function from the form input it will compare it with eval(2+2). If its correct do this else do that. But I cant get the syntax to work